# Sort on 'first_name' instead of 'full-name' in Backgrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, backgrid

Using backgrid, displaying users list. 'User' model having first_name and last_name attributes.
I have wrote method full_name on user model and displaying that full name into backgrid.

```
{
  name: "full_name",
  label: "Name",
  editable: false,
  cell: 'string'
}
```

On server  side using will_pagination. When I clicks on full_name to sort. 
It gives error -  "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "full_name" does not exist".

So I need to sort on first_name instead of full_name. But I don't know how to do? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On server side, this can be handled by overriding the param 'sort_by' value and order. We can pass multiple columns in order. In this case instead of 'full_name', applied order on first_name and last_name.
For example:

```
User.paginate(page: params[:current_page], per_page: params[:pageSize]).order("first_name asc, last_name asc")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting with `full_name` make it sortable with `first_name`. Don't use `full_name` in your will_paginate and backgrid configurations.

Comment: want to show full_name of user in table. Question is - How to set sorting on first_name instead of full_name in backgrid?

Comment: in table if you want to add full-name in you table then you have to add it in attribute accessible in your model and generate and run a migration.

Comment: @users = User.paginate(
              page: params[:current_page],
              per_page: params[:pageSize]
            ).order("#{params[:sort_by]} #{params[:order]}") 
I want to show full_name into grid of users.

Comment: In the question you are saying "I need to sort on first_name instead of full_name" now you are saying " I want to show full_name into grid of users". I cant understand what you wanna do.

Comment: Its means that I want show value of full_name into 'Name' column of users backgrid but at time of sorting, sort by first_name for this column 'Name'. Is it clear?

Comment: Use ".sort_by" method